# Assigning grease pencil vertices to vertex group

Tags: grease-pencil, vertex-groups

I'm writing a piece of code where I want to assign the selected grease pencil vertices to a vertex group. So far, with the vertices selected, this is what I have tried:

```
#create vertex group:
obj.vertex_groups.new(name = 'TEST')
#assign selected vertices to group:
bpy.ops.gpencil.vertex_group_assign()
```

However, this doesn't work. It creates the vertex group no problem, but doesn't assign anything to it. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have vertices selected at that point?

Comment: Yes, vertices are selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out that you need to override the context for this operator.

```
#create vertex group:
obj.vertex_groups.new(name = 'TEST')

#assign selected vertices to group:
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                override = {'area': area, 'region': region, 'edit_object':bpy.context.edit_object}

bpy.ops.gpencil.vertex_group_assign(override)
```